# How to copy files that match a glob pattern with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following local set of files:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2
.
./.DS_Store
./radio
./radio/server.properties
./radio/recordings/
./radio/requirements.txt
./radio/__pycache__
./radio/radio.iml
./radio/radio.py
./radio/audio.py
./ansibleplaybook.yml
./inventory
```

I would like to copy only the `.py` files such that my remote server looks like this:

```
$ find ~/radio/
/home/pi/radio/
/home/pi/radio/radio.py
/home/pi/radio/audio.py
```

I have used examples found here and in the Ansible documentation to come up with this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Copy radio source
      copy:
        src: "radio"
        dest: "~/radio"
      with_fileglob:
        - "*.py"
```

However, run I run this no directory is created and nothing is copied.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory ansibleplaybook.yml -u pi

PLAY [pi] **************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [pi]

TASK [Copy radio source] **********************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
pi              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If I specify the .py files individually then the radio directory is created and the .py file is copied. I know I only have two .py files now, but having to update my playbook every time I add a new python module will obviously start to get very tedious. How can I get the above playbook to work so that all the files that match the pattern are copied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think part of your confusion is that `with_fileglob` doesn't know anything about the parameters to the `copy` module, so it doesn't know you want files relative to the `radio` directory. Consider, for example, what happens if you run this shell command from your home directory:

```
ls *.py
```

It won't find those `*.py` files, either, because they're inside the
`radio` directory.

Because `with_fileglob` returns no results, the task never runs.

There are a number of ways of tackling this problem. Note that in the following examples I'm using a destination of `/tmp/target` to avoid cluttering up my home directory with test files.

### Recursive copy

If you remove the `with_fileglob` loop, then Ansible will recursively copy the contents of the local `radio` directory to `~/radio` on the target host. This will copy *all* the files, not just the Python sources.

### Use `find` module to generate a list of files

If you really want *only* the Python sources, you can use the `find` module to generate a list of matching files, and then use that as input to the `copy` module. In this case, you will need to take care of creating target directories yourself, because `copy` won't do that for you.

Something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: radio
        patterns: "*.py"
      register: python_files

    - name: Create target directories
      file:
        path: "/tmp/target/{{ item.path|dirname }}"
        state: directory
      loop: "{{ python_files.files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"

    - name: Copy files
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
        dest: "/tmp/target/{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ python_files.files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

### Use the `synchronize` module

You could use the [`synchronize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) module to copy the files instead. `synchronize` is a wrapper around `rsync` so in many ways it's more appropriate to the task at hand. That might look like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - synchronize:
        src: radio/
        dest: /tmp/target/
        rsync_opts:
          - '--include=*.py'
          - '--include=*/'
          - '--exclude=*'
```

See the `rsync` man page for more information about the `--include` and `--exclude` options.

Comment: Thank you so much for not only giving such a detailed answer but explaining why my thinking about `with_fileglob` was wrong. `synchronize` certainly seems to better fit what I'm trying to do. I was able to use it to copy all the .py files along with a properties file. It also runs much faster than the other methods. I had to remove `'--include=*/'` though because I don't need it to recurse the source directory. Funnily enough there are no examples of `--include` is the docs for `synchronize`.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is actually this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Copy radio source
    copy:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "~/radio/"
    with_fileglob:
      - "radio/*.py"
```

Note the trailing slash "/" on the dest to ensure writing to a directory.
And as larsks says the "with" part do not know anything about the parameters to Copy. Actually the with_fileglob is used to create the parameters to copy, thus the  `"{{ item }}"` as src that reffers to the items provided by the "with" part, you can almost look at it as a loop over the task.

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html